# PHP & MySql create tabulated data grid and save in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am working in a project where I have following scenario.

I want to create tabulated form at run time. see image below

[image]

I want a control like where user can drag and drop, provide number of rows and columns, labels of rows and columns and save it in mysql database.

Later other users will fetch this table from database and fill different column values.

**Problem:**

What will be the database schema for this dynamic data grid?

Is there any jQuery plugin to create such editable grid?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in the comment at `Moshe Shaham`'s answer: *"Actually i am creating a template system for surveys"*. Then:

1. Make a database table to keeping `Survey` data.

   `servey_id`,`title`, etc.
2. Make a database table to keeping `Question` data, linked to the `survey_id`.

   `question_id`,`survey_id`,`title`,`type`,`order`
3. Make database tables to keeping `Answer` data, linked to the `question_id`.

   boolean: `answer_id`,`question_id`,`value/tinyint(1)`

   numeric: `answer_id`,`question_id`,`value/int(11)`

   text: `answer_id`,`question_id`,`value/varchar(255)`

As you see you need multiple tables for `Answers`, because usually you expecting different data for some questions.

Later you can query and make your tables on-the-fly.

I guess it's the most common way on making such a structure.

Regarding the `jQuery` part, you can just make the table on-the-fly and then use any kinda libraries or jQuery plug-ins for sorting, formatting, styling, etc.

Comment: thanx for your answer but my question was not related to survey to display in grid. In my survey there are questions and answers as you posted above, but along with questions in my survey there are data grids as I showed you in my question. My question was about grid in survey. Create dynamic grid and save it as part of survey and later show to the users to fill survey.

Comment: @IrfanDANISH Can you store the grid as a `JSON` encoded data in filed in your database? How much data is in there? If you do so, later you can extract it and make it on-the-fly again.

Comment: I have to save values against this grid from different users. If i have grid structure as JSON encoded string then how can i save answers of this grid?

Comment: @IrfanDANISH Imagine you have an array of column names and another array which contains all the data/rows. Each row is a separated array. You can save the separately or merge them together and then save it as a `JSON` string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward solution will be to simply [create a new table](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp) in the database for each new table the user creates. unless we are talking about a huge number of tables, i think it's simple and easy to work with, since you can let the users select the data type of the column. doing all the custom table in one huge generic table can turn into a mess...

Comment: No it will not be feasible, Actually i am creating a template system for surveys. Each survey can have multiple data grids as i showed you in my question. So there are number of templates, and number of tabulated data grids.